# Get value of UL item being repeated by PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a UL lists being created dynamically from MySQL.  When I select one of the items I would like to have it submit that value into a different table.  So I guess I would like to turn the list itself into a form. (not sure if that's the correct thinking though).

```
<?php include_once "Connections/myDatabase.php";  ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.selectable {
    display: list-item;
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: Light;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT client_name FROM clients";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<li class='selectable'> " . $row["client_name"]. "</li>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                    ?>
        </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can make it a `form` or a link with a `GET` parameter, or write some JS to pull the value and send it via AJAX.

Comment: The question is about PHP/HTML, not Mysql or SQL, I'm remove tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it if you use  and  in html, because you can get value from option on change.

```
<select name="list">
    <option value='1'> item one </option>
</select>
```

Post it with a Form, and take it with $_POST["list"].

:-)